# sql optimisation for classifying and COUNT() by integer value

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have table like this.

```
table ppsscore
string name, int playlevel , int scoretotal,
```

- playlevel takes 0-1
- scoretotal takes 0-100

There are more than 1 million rows.

I would like to classify the rows by playlevel and scoretotal then count the rows.

However it takes too much time.

At first, I made indexing 'playlevel' and 'scoretotal', but not so much different.

Is there any other good way to optimisation for count?

```
  hash['level1']['over100'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal = '100'").count    
  hash['level1']['over90'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '90' AND scoretotal != '100'").count
  hash['level1']['over80'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '80' AND scoretotal < '90'").count
  hash['level1']['over70'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '70' AND scoretotal < '80'").count
  hash['level1']['over60'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '60' AND scoretotal < '70'").count
  hash['level1']['over50'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '50' AND scoretotal < '60'").count
  hash['level1']['over40'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '40' AND scoretotal < '50'").count
  hash['level1']['over30'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '30' AND scoretotal < '40'").count
  hash['level1']['over20'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '20' AND scoretotal < '30'").count
  hash['level1']['over10'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '10' AND scoretotal < '20'").count
  hash['level1']['over0'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '1' AND scoretotal >= '0' AND scoretotal < '10'").count


  hash['level0']['over100'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal = '100'").count    
  hash['level0']['over90'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '90' AND scoretotal != '100'").count
  hash['level0']['over80'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '80' AND scoretotal < '90'").count
  hash['level0']['over70'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '70' AND scoretotal < '80'").count
  hash['level0']['over60'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '60' AND scoretotal < '70'").count
  hash['level0']['over50'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '50' AND scoretotal < '60'").count
  hash['level0']['over40'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '40' AND scoretotal < '50'").count
  hash['level0']['over30'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '30' AND scoretotal < '40'").count
  hash['level0']['over20'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '20' AND scoretotal < '30'").count
  hash['level0']['over10'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '10' AND scoretotal < '20'").count
  hash['level0']['over0'] = Ppscore.where("playlevel = '0' AND scoretotal >= '0' AND scoretotal < '10'").count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in one query:

```
select playlevel, concat('over',floor(scoretotal/10)*10) score, count(*) c
from ppsscore
group by playlevel, concat('over',floor(scoretotal/10)*10)
```

Comment: thanks I have been totaly wrong about mysql strategy.